# How do I get AI allies to hand over their resources?

Tags: stronghold-crusader

Several missions on the crusader trail grant you AI-controlled allies. They're mostly useless, at best acting as a distraction against incoming attacks. However, since they get the same resource bonuses as the enemy, they're usually flush with gold and other resources.

The game also has a feature to request items from allies. These requests are typically rejected. Is there a reliable way to get AI players to agree to hand over the resources they barely use? I have no idea what goes into the decision making for whether or not they'll help you out or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a reliable way.
From what I understand from the description of the AI from the [site](https://unofficialcrusaderpatch.github.io/aic/detailed.html) of the unofficial patch this behaviour is controlled by a single AI-specific variable.

> MinimumGoods
> Required
> AfterTrade
> Integer
> The AI will only send ally a good if they have this at least amount to spare

Alternatively said, if the AI would have less than this amount of a good after sending them, it won't send them to the requesting player.

For example, assuming that [these](https://github.com/UnofficialCrusaderPatch/UnofficialCrusaderPatch/blob/master/resources/aic/vanilla.json) vanilla values are correct, the Snake still needs 10 of the resource after the transfer in order to accept it.
The Pig, on the other hand, still wants to keep at least 100 of the resource.

There might still be some other factors at play, but this is the only one I could find.

Comment: I just tried it with the snake, and "will give, as long as it leaves him with at least 10 items left" seems like how it works. It's difficult to try and estimate how much he can spare, and he doesn't seem to stockpile much. Except gold - but even with 10,000 gold in his treasure he won't spare 10. I'm guessing they just never send gold by request, which is a shame because 99% of the time that's what I really need.